# Reputation box for a specific question went missing when reputation became zero!

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation, design

Consider the following scenario:

[image]

On SO, my reputation box shows that I earned no reputation for a specific question. But there is no such box actually! It is missing! (as specified in the image above)

Instead, it should show a box with `+0` as reputation, like it shows for vote counts of a question:

[image]

For the same question, it does show -3 votes:

[image]

What actually happened is that I got a few upvotes and a few downvotes on this question, resulting in no change in my reputation.

In such cases, I expect the UI to display a box with 0 or +0 written in it.
I think it is a bug. If otherwise, please correct me.

Comment: Why does it matter at all?

Comment: It may not be a critical bug, but it is a bug nevertheless.